Is there any idea to visualize the JSON data to make it easier to understand?
We know that JSON is used to save data. If the amount of data is extremely large, then JSON will seem difficult to understand conveniently. Therefore, there is a UX design requirement to visually display JSON data so that JSON data can be easily understood.
I have tried two ways to visually display it, but I feel that neither can match the structural information of JSON:

Table method
Problem: Objects cannot be displayed conveniently.
Box framework method
Problem: It also doesn't seem easy to understand.



Can you add more context? What is the use case for example?

I use JSON-Visualizer is a mix from your two options and can give you a good context about the information you're about to request or pass to the method in your app, but also I think it could be better.
https://www.jsonvisual.com/
At least you can take this as an inception to continue on your journey.
